# I don't understand why am I getting this output in this C program

Tags: arrays, c, string, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {

    char s1[6] = "Hello";
    char s2[3];

    strcpy(s2, s1);

    printf("%s\n", s2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have written this code in C and expected the output to be either an error
or maybe s2 will be {'H', 'e', '\0'} but the actual output was a "Hello" (without "") just like s1
so why did this happen considering that s2 should only hold up to 3 chars which is smaller than s1 size.

Comment: `strcpy(s2, s1);` = *undefined behavior*. There isn't sufficient space in `s2` to hold the full length of `s1` and its terminator. [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) doesn't know, nor care whether the destination you provided is large enough to hold what you asked. That responsibility lays with *you*. Heed the warning: "The behavior is undefined if the dest array is not large enough."

Comment: You've overflowed the buffer, but your string still exists in memory. It just exists in some memory that it shouldn't. C doesn't do run-time bounds checking.

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior. `strcpy` performs no bounds checking, it has no idea how large the space you've asked it to copy into is and doesn't care.

Comment: `s2` is only ***guaranteed*** to hold 3 characters.   More space might actually be available, but that extra space is not guaranteed, and using it may result in errors, unexplained weird behavior, or even "correct" operation.

Comment: Try to use `strncpy()` in your code to remind you of your buffer limitations; try not to use `strcpy.`

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: @mpez0 strncpy should also be avoided for entirely different reasons, namely the non-intuitive interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having placed your code in `question.c`, let's do a little debugging to figure out what is happening.

```
$ gcc -Wall -fstack-protector-strong -g -o question question.c
$ ./question 
Hello
```

So far none of the warnings you get with `-Wall` or `-fstack-protector-strong` have helped us to catch this issue. So let's try `valgrind`:

```
$ valgrind -q ./question 
==1313263== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0x1ffefff73f, 0x1ffefff742)
==1313263==    at 0x484EF00: strcpy (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1313263==    by 0x1091C3: main (question.c:10)
==1313263== 
Hello
```

Looks like `valgrind` has provided a clue that something is wrong here. Let's try debugging it.

```
$ gdb ./question 
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1195: file question.c, line 5.

(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, main () at question.c:5
5   int main(void) {

(gdb) n
7       char s1[6] = "Hello";
(gdb) n
10      strcpy(s2, s1);
(gdb) n
12      printf("%s\n", s2);
(gdb) p s1
$1 = "lo\000lo"
(gdb) p s2
$2 = "Hel"
(gdb) p (char*) s2
$3 = 0x7fffffffd7cf "Hello"
```

From the above debug session you can kind of see what is *really* going on:

- Because `gdb` knows that `s2` is only a three-byte array, printing it out dislays `Hel`.
- You can see by printing out `s1` that the remainder of the string has *overflowed* into `s1`.

Why did it do this? It's due how how the variables were laid out on the stack when you ran the program. You can check for yourself by dumping the stack in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) p $sp
$4 = (void *) 0x7fffffffd7c0
(gdb) p &s1
$5 = (char (*)[6]) 0x7fffffffd7d2
(gdb) p &s2
$6 = (char (*)[3]) 0x7fffffffd7cf
```

This shows the in-memory addresses of the stack, and the addresses of `s1` and `s2`. By printing out a hex dump of the stack, you can also visualize this:

```
(gdb) dump binary memory stackdump $sp $sp+32
(gdb) shell xxd stackdump
00000000: e9dc ffff ff7f 0000 6400 0000 0000 0048  ........d......H
00000010: 656c 6c6f 006c 6f00 0002 9cd6 42c9 4be5  ello.lo.....B.K.
```

You can see from the above that 15 bytes into the stack is where `s2` was, and confirm that as follows:

```
(gdb) p (char*) $sp+15
$7 = 0x7fffffffd7cf "Hello"
(gdb) p (char*) s2
$8 = 0x7fffffffd7cf "Hello"
```

... and similarly, you can see that `s1` was 18 bytes into the stack and has been overwritten by the write to `s2`:

```
(gdb) p (char*) $sp+18
$10 = 0x7fffffffd7d2 "lo"
(gdb) p (char*) s1
$11 = 0x7fffffffd7d2 "lo"
```